# How can I properly make this into an image border?

Tags: html, css, border-image

Since I'm not sure if this programmatic-wise or photo edit-wise, I'm posting this here. I apologize if I had to post this somewhere else.

---

Anyways, I'm trying to use the `border-image` property to make a nice border using this image:
[image: Image of the border I found on the web]

But it's not really working out with me. I'm getting weird appearences. Here's my code:

```css
#div{
        -webkit-border-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/BL9Mb7a.gif") 30 repeat; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
        -o-border-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/BL9Mb7a.gif") 30 repeat; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
        border-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/BL9Mb7a.gif") 30 repeat;
     border-width: 100px;
     border-style: solid;
     height: 200px;
     width: 100px;
    }
```

```html
  <body>
  <div id="div">Hello world!!!</div>
  </body>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0721wtj2/)

So, I need some tips on fixing this. The results should turn out *something* like this (Not exactly, similarly):

[image: Similarly, the border should look like this]

**Note that the width won't be defined. Could be extended**

Pretty much, It should be repeating the middle part of the image and leaving the edges. But I'm getting a result of a newborn's drawings. So, is there any tips or solutions for this?? I've done research but none include my desires.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp is a useful link, maybe? Try fiddling about with the different properties until you get what you want

Comment: try `border-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/BL9Mb7a.gif") 20% round;` will make a difference :)

Comment: @GeoffJames Thanks, but I already saw it.

Comment: @M.Tanzil Thanks, but it didn't work. Btw, if you can suggest an already done border like the second image above, that'll work if I use it, then it'll be great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the image you're using for the border. The image that you're using is trying to be sliced up into each section of the border. `border-image` is not designed to take an image and line it up across the perimeter; it's designed to be split up into 9 sections (think tic-tac-toe board) where the center is your *div area*.

[image: Sliced Image]

Now each slice of the image is trying to be applied to your respective borders, where the sides can be repeated, as in your case. [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/#article-header-id-2) has a nice page about this.

One way to possibly fix this, is to edit the image you want on your own, and set up your own borders via. copy-paste and rotation. This way you can slice out the appropriate sections when using it in CSS.

Comment: Thanks but I already solved my own problem, this information will be helpful to other users though.

Comment: By making my own border as you said: https://s32.postimg.org/rfht7aqx1/border.png

Comment: But I realized this before you said so, so I told a mod to close this. But since the topic is useful then maybe not.

Comment: Nice. Pretty nice new border :)